# how to pass json string to line highchart?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, highcharts

I am working with basic line highchart and i have json string being passed by php.

I want to pass that string to highchart but its not working for me. I don't know where i am wrong.

My code is as follows :

```
// data['SeriesData'] = [{"name":"Support Help Desk","data":[0,0,0,3060,675,0,450,540,112.5,0,45,45]},{"name":"Business Activity","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"Maintenance Tasks","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"Development","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,832.5,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"Consulting Services","data":[0,0,0,1237.5,3802.5,3166.5,2801,585,562.5,0,157.5,1822.5]}]

var jdata = data['SeriesData'];
var SData = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + jdata + ")"));

 $('#chart').highcharts({           
            title: {
                text: 'Line Chart',
                 x: -20 //center
            },          
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },          
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Total Minutes'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },          
            tooltip: {
                  valueSuffix: 'min'
            },
            series: SData
        });
```

Can someone point me to my mistake please ??

Comment: `var SData = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + jdata + ")"));` has to be wrong. Just has to be. What's wrong with `JSON.stringify(jdata)`?

Comment: still not working. Its not recognizing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works: [**Live demo (click).**](http://jsbin.com/UQupAvI/1/edit)

```
var data = {};
data.seriesData = [
  {"name":"Support Help Desk","data":[0,0,0,3060,675,0,450,540,112.5,0,45,45]},  
  {"name":"Business Activity","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
  {"name":"Maintenance Tasks","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
  {"name":"Development","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,832.5,0,0,0,0]},
  {"name":"Consulting Services","data":[0,0,0,1237.5,3802.5,3166.5,2801,585,562.5,0,157.5,1822.5]}
];

var sData = JSON.stringify(data.seriesData);
console.log(sData);
```

Note that I changed it to use dot notation and the standard camelCase naming. Here's a demo of your original code with the correct change - works either way:  http://jsbin.com/UQupAvI/2/edit

`eval()` is almost never the answer. I don't know what lead you to use it, but you don't need it. You had a JSON object already. If you need a string of it, you just need `JSON.stringify()`. If you have a string and need an object, you use `JSON.parse()`.

I'm assuming you approached the whole thing awkwardly - it sounds like you actually want to turn a string from the server into an actual object: **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/UQupAvI/3/edit)**

```
var data = {};
data.seriesData = '[{"name":"Support Help Desk","data":[0,0,0,3060,675,0,450,540,112.5,0,45,45]},{"name":"Business Activity","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"Maintenance Tasks","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"Development","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,832.5,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"Consulting Services","data":[0,0,0,1237.5,3802.5,3166.5,2801,585,562.5,0,157.5,1822.5]}]';

var sData = JSON.parse(data.seriesData);
console.log(sData); //now an object
```

Comment: hey still not working.. and this demo is also not working.. what r u passing in highchart ?

Comment: @Mausami do you need to pass a string or an object?

Comment: i want to pass this data to the chart to get the chart working. so i am trying both way to get it working. but its not working in anyway. if i use JSON.parse(data.seriesData) than its giving me syntax error.

Comment: @Mausami you aren't making sense.  Your post shows that you have a javascript object, but you're saying that it is a string from the server. I'm assuming you want to get a string from the server and pass it as an object to your function, so you need `JSON.parse(stringFromServer)`. If that's the case, use the second code block from my answer.

Comment: i am converting my result to json on my php page and i am using that json to make the chart. data["SeriesData"] is my json result. and i want to pass it to the highchart. but i dont know how to do that. so i tried to covert my result in both string and object. but unfortunately its not working. and i don't know why ?

Comment: i tried JSON.parse(data["SeriesData"]) but its giving me this error "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'"

Comment: @Mausami Tell me what the result of `console.log(typeof data.SeriesData)` is.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44661/discussion-between-mausami-and-m59)